# Windows Server start Add Roles and Features Wizard command

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server

***I am trying to find a way to start the Add Roles and Features Wizard using a command***, much how you can open Windows Features by typing `optionalfeatures` on Windows 7 and above. I want to create a shortcut to jump straight to the Wizard without having to open Server Manager first and then navigate to it via the menu. As the wizard is part of servermanager.exe (i.e. a Server Manager sub-process), I am assuming there may be a switch that can be passed to it, but I have not been able to find this. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: As you already said it's part of `ServerManager` apparently so you'd have to start him anyway. You could use `dism`, `sconfig` or the PowerShell (`Add-WindowsFeature etc.`) if you want to avoid it. Don't forget that you could actually manage other servers with the current server manager as well.

Comment: Sure, but the goal here is to jump straight to the Add Roles and Features Wizard, bypassing the menu to get to it. Surely there has to be a way to do this, as if you open `appwiz.cpl` and then click `Turn Windows features on and off`, it starts Server Manager and opens the Wizard directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can get directly to it, but it does still launch server manager:

```
ServerManager.exe -arw
```